# Configuring EMR notebook with azurerepo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, azure-repos

How do i configure emr notebook to user azure repo?

Is these possible to connect azure repo to emr notebook, in the documentation i found only these
You can associate Git-based repositories with your Amazon EMR notebooks to save your notebooks in a version controlled environment. You can associate up to three repositories with a notebook. The following Git-based services are supported:

AWS CodeCommit

GitHub

Bitbucket

GitLab